# The eval function

Tags: matlab, eval

I am trying to learn MATLAB on my own. In the book I am using there is a script example involving `eval` which is as follows:

```
 t = [0:0.1:2]
 for k = 1:10
    outputfile = ['result',int2str(k)];
    theta = k*pi*t;
    x = sin(theta);
    y = cos(theta);
    z = x.*y.^2;
    eval(['save ',outputfile,' x y z'])
end
```

My questions is - why is it necessary to include `' x y z'` at the end of the `eval` command? I tried running this script without including this, and, as far as I can tell, the script looks to behave exactly the same (at least I can't find any difference).

If anyone can explain to me why this is included, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: That's a horrible example! People should not be taught to use `eval`, and certainly not when there is a perfectly good `eval`-free syntax available.

Comment: Yes, I wondered about the purpose of "eval" myself.  Why not just use "save"?  I think the purpose of this example was just to show how "eval" can be used, but it does not mean that the book actually encourages the use of it when saving scripts/functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `'x y z` are arguments to the `save` function/command. They are telling `save` which variables to save to the file `outputfile`. See the MATLAB [documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/save.html) for more information on the `save` command.

Note: you could replace that line with a call to the `save` function, as per the MATLAB documentation. For example, you could just use

```
save(outputfile, 'x', 'y', 'z')
```

Answer (score 2):

Without `x y z`, your output file (.mat file) will contain all the variables in the workspace (i.e. `x y z theta t k ...`). If you only want to store `x y z`, then you specify it when calling [`save`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/save.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot!  Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why using the function ***'eval'*** is that by using eval you can save a list result named as result_1 result_2... at once.
Namely, Saving data to incrementally numbered ASCII files.
You can find more detail at this websit:

> https://www3.nd.edu/~dtl/cheg258/notes/doc/tec1.3.html

Notice: There is a blank space in eval(['save ',outputfile,' x y z']) before letter x.